# How to install pyQt in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, ubuntu-14.04

I need to install pyQt in ubuntu 14.04 version. BUt when I use

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

Then, I got some error like:

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxslt/libxslt1-dev_1.1.28-2build1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17389307/6918812

Comment: yes I tried that too @Shubham

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get --fix-missing && sudo apt-get install python-pyqt4`

Comment: when I execute that:                                                                                GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)                                                                                                  eyllanesc